# How to insert to MySQL data from dynnamically generated row with multiple select?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

```
tableA   tabA_id   name     value         
------------------------------------
Row1       25      nameA    1.25    
Row2       26      nameB    4.85    
Row3       27      nameA    3.25    

tableB   tabA_id   mytabA_id   multiple_tabA_id
--------------------------------------------------
Row1       25         1               1
Row2       25         1               3
Row3       25         1               4
Row4       26         2               1
Row5       26         2               2
Row6       27         1               1
Row7       27         1               2
Row8       27         1               4

tableC   tabC_id   name   
--------------------------
Row1        1      nameA               
Row2        2      nameB              
Row3        3      nameC               
Row4        4      nameD
```

Table C is list of users. Table A is table where we have name of users, values. And in Table B we have similar view like tableA, because mytabA_id is name from tableA and multiple_tabA_id is ids of these users who are in multiple array.

**First** problem is to save multiple select to DB (to table A). **Second** problem is INSERT rows to tableB depends on tableA.

I want to dynamically add new row in table A.
I have a source to add new line by JQuery. I think it is good.

```
function Add(){
counter += 1;

    $("#example2 tbody").last().append(
        "<tr>"+
        "<td>"+counter+ "</td>"+
        "<td><input id='name_" + counter + "' type='text' class='form-control'/></td>"+
        "<td><input id='value_" + counter + "' type='text' class='form-control'/></td>"+
        "<td><select multiple class='form-control' id='multiple'>"+
    "<?php $sql = mysql_query('select tabC_id, name from tableC'); while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ $name=$row['name']; $tabC_id=$row['tabC_id']; ?> <option value='<?echo $tabC_id;?>'><?echo $name;?></option><?}?>"+
    "</select></td>"+
    "<td><img src='./img/save-icon.png' class='btnSave'/><img src='img/delete-icon.png' class='btnDelete'/></td>"+
        "</tr>"
    );

        $(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);      
        $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
};
```

OK. Than I save typed values to variables and send them to php file. It is correct with text, but I dont know if it is correct with multiple select. Please find me a bugs.

```
function Save(){ 
   var par = $(this).parent().parent(); 

   var tdname = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
   var tdvalue = par.children("td:nth-child(3)"); 
   var tdmultiple = par.children("td:nth-child(4)"); 

   var name = tdname.children("input[type=text]").val();
   var value = tdvalue.children("input[type=text]").val();
   var multiple = $( "#multiple" ).val() || [];

jQuery.post("table_save_ajax.php", {
   name:name,
   value:value,
   multiple:multiple
   },  function(data, textStatus){
      if(data == 1){
         $('#response').html("Successfull!!");
         $('#response').css('color','green');
         $('td:nth-child(5)').hide();

         tdname.html(tdname.children("input[type=text]").val());
         tdvalue.html(tdvalue.children("input[type=text]").val());
         tdmultiple.html(multiple.join( ", " ));

      }else{
         $('#response').html("Some Error Occurred");
         $('#response').css('color','red');
      }
   });
```

**table_save_ajax.php**

in config is only connection to DB. It is correct.

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$name = $_POST['name'];
$value = $_POST['value'];
$multiple = $_POST['multiple'];
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableA (name, value, multiple) VALUES ('$name','$value','$multiple')");

if(mysql_affected_rows()>0){
echo "1";
}else{
echo "2";
}
?>
```

All things are correct without multiple select. And I want to know how to do it correct with multiple select. And I want to know how to INSERT data to tableB. How to parse this data from array and save to DB.
Thank you for your response.

Comment: You'll want to `mysql_escape_string` your input ($_POST['name'], $_POST['value'], etc), or even better use mysqli or PDO and use prepared statements/bindValue).

Comment: ok but now i dont want to solve security of code... I want to solve functionality...

Comment: when somebody dont know answer, pls give me vote plus. Next I want to upload images. This is not very nice to write tables like code... Thank you.

Comment: I don't think that's the purpose of up vote :), if people aren't answering your question, think about rephrasing the question or rethinking about what you're asking.  I suppose to insert into tableB, you first need to select the id from tableA after you insert new rows (or you could use `mysql_insert_id()`).

Comment: you think id of the row or id of the multiple names?

Comment: I can change it. I dont have to save names in multiple in table A when I will have table B.

Comment: when I write simple question it is bad... when I write long question it is bad too... where is the right way?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, and it is good for me.
It is **table_save_ajax.php**

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableA (name, value) VALUES ('$name','$value')");

if($sql){
    $sqlselect = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM tableA ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
    if(mysql_num_rows($sqlselect) == 1){
      $row=mysql_fetch_array($sqlselect);
      $lastid=$row['id'];

      foreach ($multiple as &$value) {
        $sqlmultiple = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableB (tabA_id, mytabA_id, multiple_tabA_id) VALUES ('$lastid', '$name', '$value',)");
        if(!$sqlmultiple){
          $sqldelete = mysql_query("DELETE FROM tableA WHERE id = '$lastid'");
        }  
      }
    } 
}
```